# What is the difference between ui:menuTrigger and ui:menuTriggerLink?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Can somebody give me example of ui:menuTrigger and how it is different from ui:menuTriggerLink? Current document doesn't have any example for  ui:menuTrigger. Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no reason to use `ui:menuTrigger`. You should always use `ui:menuTriggerLink` instead. Here's an example with explanation for a component that uses `ui:menuTriggerLink`:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_menu.htm

Answer (score 1):

It is not documented but I have used ui:menuTrigger for using button and custom template instead of link.

```
<ui:menuTrigger>
  <!-- button or custom template -->
</ui:menuTrigger>
```